# What is the difference between listen 443 ssl http2 AND listen [::]:443 ssl http2?

Tags: nginx

I am looking at this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0#https-configuration

There is a sample of the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` provided.

The server has got 2 listens as follows:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ...
   }
```

What is the difference between 1st listen and the 2nd listen?

The 1st listen seems to listen for any request on port 443, where as the 2nd listen seems to listen for any requests with any source IP on port 443?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen), the first `listen` directive is for IPv4 and second one is for IPv6 protocol.